# google pay UPI integration in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

i'm finding a solution for getting direct payment to my account using Googlepay and phonepay UPI like flipkart please provide me solution in php codeigniter

Comment: This should help you- https://developers.google.com/pay/india/api/otherapis/omnichannel/googlepay-business, https://razorpay.com/docs/payment-gateway/payment-methods/upi/google-pay/custom-integration/